# Subtracting quarters from a pandas Period

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following pandas Period

```
p = pd.Period('2021Q4')
```

This represents a date `2021-12-31`. Is it possible to subtract quarters from this period, i.e., subtract 1, 2, 3 or 4 quarters from this to get `pd.Period('2021Q3')`, `pd.Period('2021Q2')`, `pd.Period('2021Q1')` and `pd.Period('2020Q4')`, respectively?

I tried the following, but it gave me a `IncompatibleFrequency` error:

```
pd.Period('2021Q4')-pd.DateOffset(years=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If subtract integers it subtract quarters, because `quarter` periods:

```
print (pd.Period('2021Q4')-1)
2021Q3

print (pd.Period('2021Q4')-2)
2021Q2
```